# org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: The FirefoxDriver cannot be used after quit()

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty(object))).click();
            System.out.println("Test");
```

Click works for some button.But on clicking a specific button in application.
But 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException' erro comes after the above driver action. Test is not printed on console after that click. Why is it so?

```
public static void click(String object, String data){
        try{
            /*try
            {
                driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
            }
            catch(Exception e){}*/      
            new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(OR.getProperty(object))));
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty(object))).click();
            System.out.println("Test");
            Log.info("Clicking on Webelement "+ object);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.error("Not able to click --- " + e.getMessage());
            DriverScript.bResult = false;
        }
    }
```

This is the code. Its a keyword driven framework. This action keyword gets executed 6 times perfectly. But on clicking some button which popups new window this error occurs. Switch window is supposed to be the next action keyword to be executed. But it is not reaching there . Just after .click it stands idle for long time. Then the above exception.

```
public static void switchwindow(String object,String data){
        try{
            parentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
            System.out.println(driver.getWindowHandles().size());// get the current window handle
            for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
                if(winHandle.equalsIgnoreCase("73e19507-bf40-44ce-822a-62630be49c2b"))
                {driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);break;} // switch focus of WebDriver to the next found window handle (that's your newly opened window)
            }
            Log.info("Switched to new window");       
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.error("Not able to switch the window --- " + e.getMessage());
            DriverScript.bResult = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: checked in other browser ???

Comment: can u paste ur sample code which is causing the problem and also few lines after that which are getting executed

Comment: application support only Mozilla

Comment: U check other browser to exclude webdriver error :-)

Comment: Tif(winHandle.equalsIgnoreCase("73e19507-bf40-44ce-822a-62630be49c2b"))  this check probably never is never successful.  Try printing out values of handlers to see if you even get into the switching window code. I would rather go with some identifier for other window.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your browser is already closed.

I would simplified tests and not call quit anywhere in code.

I would also tried if problem exist in other browsers. Also U could debug or introduce sleeps to check where execly problem is.

Comment: I tried sleep just after the click but it is not reaching there.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there could be an issue with your code for switching windows. It would be better to debug if you could show the code for switching windows.

Comment: Given the code for switching window. But my execution is not reaching that point. It clicks on the button to load the window. And it is not exiting from the click action.

Comment: Is your code " System.out.println("Test"); " executes properly ?

Comment: No. That's what I confused

Comment: So, is it moving to the catch block ?  if yes, please post the error catched